# Depend on abstractions, not on concretions

Tags: php, dependency-injection, structure

For example I want to write my project without any frameworks but with ready-made libraries, not to reinvent bicycle.

But of course within evolution of project I will write my own classes that could be moved out of the project, for example it would be `\Acme\Framework` namespace. And my project files with domain layer will be placed under `\Acme\ProjectName` namespace.

So at the point I want to use Symfony's `HttpFoundation` component to deal with http layer. And I need to inject `Request` class into the controllers. But SOLID principles say that classes need to depend on abstractions instead of concretions.

Does it mean I need to create class `\Acme\Framework\Request` that depends on Symfony's `Request` and use it? Or I can use Symfony's `Request` as is.

What about the best practices in this case?

*Excuse me for my english, if it hurts you*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it means is that you generally need to depend on generic interfaces. Taking your HttpFoundation Request example, you could wrap it into [PSR-7 adapter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/psr7.html) and make your controller accept `Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface`. Now it doesn't depend on specifics of Symfony's HttpFoundation, and is able to work (with some additional effort, of course) with other frameworks that use PSR HTTP message interfaces, like Zend Expressive (there must be many more at this point).